# Семантика указателей/ссылок на const в языках C и C++

Tags: c++, c, указатели, const, ссылка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что говорят стандарты `C` и `C++` о семантике указателя/ссылки на константу?

(Да, я знаю, что в `C` нет ссылок)

Меня смущают следующие неясности:

- Кто-то говорит, что указатель/ссылка на константное значение - это лишь путь доступа к объекту. То есть, указатель/ссылка на константу - это фильтр, который запрещает менять целевой объект (на этапе компиляции). Но, в то же время, через указатель/ссылку на константу можно увидеть факт изменения состояния целевого объекта.
- Кто-то говорит, что компилятор может решить, что указатель/ссылка на константное значение обозначает, что целевое значение не может быть изменено.

  Например:

  ```
  // Somewhere far.
  int source_value = 0;
  some_function(&source_value, &source_value);

  // Somewhere farther.
  void some_function(const int* a, int* b)
  {
      cout << *a << endl:
      *b = 1;
      cout << *a << endl;// Do we have guarantee that *a has 1?
  }
  ```
- С другой стороны, существуют Правила Строгих Псевдонимов (`Strict Aliasing Rules`), которые явно разрешают делать псевдоним для типа через указатель/ссылку на `cv-квалифицированный` вариант целевого типа. На мой взгляд, это правило подтверждает тот факт, что указатель/ссылка на константное значение может использоваться для обнаружения факта изменения целевого объекта, даже если код, в котором происходит наблюдение, понятия не имеет о том, что исходный объект является изменяемым и в принципе способен изменить свое состояние.

Я пытался читать черновики стандартов `C11` и `C++17`, но мне не удалось найти информацию, которая развеяла бы все мои сомнения.

Comment: фишка в том, что первый пункт не противоречит второму

Comment: Вот именно, это меня и смущает.

Comment: Правильный вариант - первый. Но ссылок на стандарты у меня тоже нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В стандарте (C11) о семантике объектов *const-qualified* типов нам по сути даны только два ограничения<sup>*</sup>:

- Из **6.3.2.1/1**: они не являются *modifiable lvalue*, и, как следствие, не могут использоваться в присваиваниях, инкрементах и т.п.
- Из **6.7.3/6**: попытка изменить их через не константный указатель — это UB.

В остальном они и указатели на них ведут себя точно также как и обычные объекты/указатели. Для них нет ни каких особых исключений.

<sup>*Есть ещё пара свобод компилятору по размещению `const`-объектов: в памяти данных, встраиванию или то что они могут накладываться друг на друга, но это к делу не относится.</sup>

---

Отсюда, по конкретным утверждениям:

> Кто-то говорит, что указатель/ссылка на константное значение - это лишь путь доступа к объекту. То есть, указатель/ссылка на константу - это фильтр, который запрещает менять целевой объект (на этапе компиляции). Но, в то же время, через указатель/ссылку на константу можно увидеть факт изменения состояния целевого объекта.

Если не придираться к словам, всё правильно.

> Кто-то говорит, что компилятор может решить, что указатель/ссылка на константное значение обозначает, что целевое значение не может быть изменено.

Вообще говоря, это не верно.

> С другой стороны, существуют Правила Строгих Псевдонимов…

Не то что подтверждает, но не противоречит и написано так, чтобы пример ниже не создавал проблем с SA...

---

По примеру:

```
void some_function(const int* a, int* b) {
    *b=1;
    printf("%d\n",*a); // если a==b, то 1
}
```

Теперь по порядку, что тут происходит с точки зрения Си:

- `*b=1` и `printf ("%d\n",*a)` находятся в разных *операторах* (*statement*).
- Согласно **annex С**, это значит, что между ними есть *точка следования* (*sequence point*).
- Согласно **5.1.2.3/2**, модификация объекта `*b=1` — это *побочный эффект*.
- И теперь согласно **5.1.2.3/3**, т.к. выражения `*b=1` и `printf("%d\n",*a)` разделены точкой следования, то все побочные эффекты вычисления `*b=1` должны *предшествовать* (*sequenced before*) выражению `printf("%d\n",*a)`.

Т.е. стандарт гарантирует, что в этом примере при `a==b` будет выведено `1`. Это не требует от компилятора выдавать машинный код, который в точности выполняет все действия, в описанной последовательности, однако основное правило оптимизации в том, что она не изменяет видимое поведение корректной программы. Так что в данном случае компилятор не вправе сначала получить значение `*a` и только потом изменить *b, не зависимо от того, есть ли `const` или нет.

Но такие строгости не всегда нужны и они не позволяют делать некоторые оптимизации. И дабы преодолеть это введены две вещи:

- Пресловутые правила `Strict Aliasing`. С ними компилятор вправе принимать на веру, что для разных типов указатели указывают на разные объекты т.к. в противном случае виноват программист,  а он, компилятор, всё сделал «как надо»:

  ```
    void some_function(int* a, float* b) {
        *b=1;
        printf("%d\n",*a); // если a==b, то UB
    }
  ```
- В С99 появился спецификатор `restrict` (в плюсах его нет, но большинство компиляторов поддерживают нестандартное ключевое слово `__restrict`). С ним, точно также, компилятор вправе считать, что указатели указывают на разные объекты:

  ```
    void some_function(int* restrict a, int* restrict b) {
        *b=1;
        printf("%d\n",*a); // если a==b, то UB
    }
  ```

---

В C++ всё примерно также, но перерывать более толстый стандарт в поисках этого мне не сильно хочется...

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за ваш ответ, он многое для меня прояснил.

Comment: Лучше использовать __restrict (или даже __restrict__), тогда его поймут не только Си, но и С++ компиляторы и этот спецификатор нужно писать после типа перед переменной (вот так -- f(int * __restrict a), иначе (по крайней мере gcc/g++) выдает ошибку).

Comment: @avp, про порядок спасибо — поправил... а про `__restrict` — не то чтобы «лучше», но добавил т.к. он поддерживается большой тройкой (`gcc`/`clang`/`msvc`)

Comment: `Есть ещё пара свобод компилятору по размещению const-объектов: в памяти данных, встраиванию или то что они могут накладываться друг на друга`. `сonst`-объекты могут накладываться друг на друга? Ссылку на стандарт бы...

Comment: @wololo,**6.5.2.5/7**: `String literals, and compound literals with const-qualified types, need not designate
distinct objects.` и сноска к нему.

Comment: А, понятно. Я решил, что речь идёт о произвольных объектах, а не литералах. Для полноты картины добавлю ссылку С++ стандарт. [lex.string/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#9): `[...] Whether all string-literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified.`.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще **const** говорит лишь о том что мы не планируем в этой части кода менять переменную. И  в реальности компилятор не делает ни каких оптимизаций основываясь лишь на этом.

**Strict Aliasing Rules** это про другое, оно говорит о том что ссылки на "*совершенно разные*" типы не должны пересекаться.

```
void foo(const float* f , int* i){
   *i = 10;
   printf("%f\n", *f);
}

int main(){
   float f = 100;
   int *i = (int*)&f; // нарушение Strict Aliasing Rules
   foo(&f, i); // UB
   return 0;
}
```

Про strict aliasing есть более подробная статья на habr:
[Что такое Strict Aliasing и почему нас должно это волновать?](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/443602/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я хорошо знаю, что такое `Strict Aliasing Rules`. На мой взгляд, это правило косвенно указывает на то, что стандарт разрешает видеть факт изменения объекта через указатель/ссылку на константу, но полной уверенности у меня нет. Нужно мнение экспертов. Очень хотелось бы услышать мнение разработчиков компиляторов, но где же их найти.

Comment: @mgneo, как вариант можно спросить в профильных каналах в телеге, [Pure C] (https://t.me/joinchat/Iw5x10-gFWVZyj-C8uBtig) и [pro.cxx](https://t.me/ProCxx/259155) там много спикеров с различных конференции и просто разработчиков любящишь пообсуждать стандарт языка.

Comment: большое спасибо за информацию!